# Reg Ex negation not working in XML string

Tags: .net, xml, regex-negation

I am trying to apply negation on regular expression in .Net. It does not work. When string has valid last name reg ex should not match. For invalid last name it should match. Valid name allows only charecters, spaces, single quote and length between 1-40. Somebody suggested to parse the XML, I don't want to do that. I know there is another way of doing this by removing the negation in reg ex and invert the match condition in code. But I don't want that too. I need pure reg ex solution for this.

Here is my code. That does match the valid last name. But I don't want to match.

```
string toBevalidated = @"<FirstName>SomeName</FirstName><LastName>Some</LastName><Address1>Addre1</Address1>";
        var regex = new Regex(@"<LastName>([^a-zA-Z'\s])|(.{41,})</LastName>");
        var match = regex.Match(toBevalidated);

        // Check to see if a match was found
        if (match.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Success");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed");
        }
```

EDIT:
There are confusion here let me give some example what I intended to to. when last name is valid reg ex should not match. For example below samples should not match the reg ex

case 1

```
<FirstName>SomeName</FirstName><LastName>Brian</LastName><Address1>Addre1</Address1>
```

Case 2

```
<FirstName>SomeName</FirstName><LastName>O'neil</LastName><Address1>Addre1</Address1>
```

case 3

```
<FirstName>SomeName</FirstName><LastName>Peter John</LastName><Address1>Addre1</Address1>
```

When last name is invalid, reg ex should match

case 4

```
<FirstName>SomeName</FirstName><LastName>Brian123</LastName><Address1>Addre1</Address1>
```

case 5

```
<FirstName>SomeName</FirstName><LastName>#Brian</LastName><Address1>Addre1</Address1>
```

case 6

```
<FirstName>SomeName</FirstName><LastName>BrianBrianBrianBrianBrianBrianBrianBrianBrianBrian</LastName><Address1>Addre1</Address1>
```

if you need more information please let me know

Comment: *Why* don't you want to parse the XML? Using regular expressions on XML is simply a bad idea - it's extremely fragile.

Comment: Why don't you continue in the question you asked yesterday what did change to start a new one, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037631/reg-ex-negation/4037708#4037708

Comment: Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for ways to improve your questions.

Comment: I want to parse the XML. But we have already 100s of reg ex already matching against XML string. That is working perfectly in production. Now I want to add one more reg ex to validate the last name. The part code is very crucial we did not want to change the code. Parsing may not right solution at this time.

Comment: @A_Nablsi I have not heard any thing after I posted my comments on your reply. Since the question I asked did not clearly specify the intend, I have created new question.

Comment: Ok let me check it again, I tested the regex I gave you and it works it does match the last name that doesn't meet your constraints.

Comment: I don't know who put the down vote here. can you provide why is that down vote here. But in my another post no one gave the correct answer and did get not reply for my comments. Actually I have to put down vote couple of answers I got in the question. They are not relevant to question I asked.

Comment: Please, listen to the man Skeet and **stop**. You think this is “working perfectly” in production, but as soon as you get anything unusual, like a character that has been escaped (`O&#39;Reilly`), or any tiny little perfectly-valid change in the XML format, like a new attribute or just some whitespace in the markup, your regexes will fail hard. This is super-brittle. .NET has good XML support that makes it incredibly easy to *correctly* extract simple XML data from formats like this. Use it and your code will be more robust *and* more readable.

Comment: @A_Nablsi Thank you for checking again. Here is the string I tested <FirstName>SomeName</FirstName><LastName>brian</LastName><Address1>Addre1</Address1>. It got matched with your reg ex. But it should not as per my question. Can you post your code if you have something different?

Comment: Having lunch and checking the regex sorry please be patient.

Comment: @amz: I suspect it's been downvoted because it's a badly written question. You didn't explain why you were rejecting the obvious solution, or give any sample code, or sample failed input/output.

Comment: I would bet folding money that, in this case, "this is working perfectly in production" means "if it fails 1% of the time we don't have any way of knowing that."

Comment: @Robert and @bobince, I respect what Skeet told. But "this is working perfectly in production" is not right phrase what I intended. I was trying to say that we believe so far that code is working fine and did not want alter the code now without considering other impacts it would cause. But after hearing from you all, we sure will revist the code and see possible changes we could make as you suggested down the road. But as far as this question concerened, we don't want to parse XML. Hope it makes clear.

Comment: @Jon: Answer to "I suspect it's been downvoted because..." I guess down vote came before solution were presented. So I did not reject any solution rightaway. Yes there are restricted options on my questions such as XML parsing because of the impact it would cause. And my question contains sample code and also I responded all the answers with sample that why that fails. Anyway I got up vote again. Thanks you Skeet for explanation.

Comment: @amz: It does *now*, but it certainly didn't to start with. Your "restricted options" were presented with no more reason than "I don't want to do that." In fact, you *still* don't present any more details in the question itself.

Comment: "But as far as this question concerened, we don't want to parse XML."  Then don't use XML.  Use a simpler format that you understand completely.  The only times people use XML without parsing it are a) when they don't understand XML or b) when they shouldn't be using XML.

Comment: Jon Skeet guessed well, I did downvoted the question because it was badly written and I tried to help but then the answer was contradictory so I got confused, and after you explained it better I pressed ctrl+z and made it up to you as well.

Comment: @Robert In this question I am trying to get the best at the situation presented to me. To use XML in your code, it does not mean that one must parse xml.

Comment: Sure, if you don't care about whether or not your software works.  Software that processes XML needs to handle character entities, namespaces, attributes, insignificant whitespace, CDATA, comments,  processing instructions, and mixed content, all of which are completely ignored by RE processing of strings assumed to be XML.  Oh, and you're assuming these strings are XML.  Since you're not parsing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have been helpful if you'd given an example of this not behaving as you expected it to, but I *suspect* it's because you're only matching an invalid character if it's a *single* invalid character, e.g.

```
<LastName>5</LastName>
```

That will match (I believe; I haven't checked) but this won't:

```
<LastName>55</LastName>
```

I *think* you could do something like:

```
<LastName>(.*[^a-zA-Z'\s].*)|(.{41,})</LastName>
```

to ensure that there's *at least* one invalid character in there (or that there are 41 or more characters). But there may be corner cases here where that's inappropriate.

EDIT: Got it. The alternation operator was taking *everything* before it as an option, instead of just the preceding group. The final regular expression is:

```
<LastName>((.*[^a-zA-Z'\s].*)|(.{41,}))</LastName>
```

And here's some sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"<LastName>((.*[^a-zA-Z'\s].*)|(.{41,}))</LastName>";
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);

        string[] samples = {
            "<FirstName>SomeName</FirstName><LastName>Brian</LastName><Address1>Addre1</Address1>",
            "<FirstName>SomeName</FirstName><LastName>O'neil</LastName><Address1>Addre1</Address1>",
            "<FirstName>SomeName</FirstName><LastName>Peter John</LastName><Address1>Addre1</Address1>",
            "<FirstName>SomeName</FirstName><LastName>Brian123</LastName><Address1>Addre1</Address1>",                
            "<FirstName>SomeName</FirstName><LastName>#Brian</LastName><Address1>Addre1</Address1>",
            "<FirstName>SomeName</FirstName><LastName>BrianBrianBrianBrianBrianBrianBrianBrianBrianBrian</LastName><Address1>Addre1</Address1>",
        };

        foreach (var sample in samples)
        {
            bool valid = !regex.IsMatch(sample);
            Console.WriteLine("Valid: {0} Text: {1}", valid, sample);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your reg ex like this <LastName>(.*[^a-zA-Z'\s].*)|(.{41,})</LastName>. But it also matches the valid last name. the string I matched <FirstName>SomeName</FirstName><LastName>brian</LastName><Address1>Addre1</Address1>.

Comment: @amz: I'll have a look when I get home.

Comment: @amz: Fixed it now - have another look.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rewrite the RegEx to:
`<LastName>([a-zA-Z'\s]{0,41})</LastName>`
and use negation in other code: `if (!match.success) ...`

Comment: Are you sure this reg ex matches <LastName>Some123</LastName>?

Comment: Or `<LastName>O&amp;Reilly</LastName>`?

Comment: No, it does not match either of these expressions, since it is supposed to only match the allowed expressions, and the rest must be done by coding.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

I couldn't get it work in one pass but if you do it in 2 passes I think it will work, first you check for the incorrect characters and in the second pass you check for the length,

```
Match m = Regex.Match(@"<FirstName>SomeName</FirstName><LastName>Some</LastName><Address1>Addre1</Address1>", "<LastName>(.*[^a-zA-Z'\\s].*)</LastName>");

m = Regex.Match(@"<FirstName>SomeName</FirstName><LastName>SomeSomSomeSomeSomeSomeSomeSomeSomeSomeeSomeSomeSomeSomeSomeSomeSome</LastName><Address1>Addre1</Address1>", "<LastName>[a-zA-Z'\\s]{41,}</LastName>");
```

I haven't checked all the cases you provided please check it out and let me know if it works.

Thanks for Skeet for the correction .*[^a-zA-Z'\s].* it does need .* before and after otherwise it won't match the names containing special characters.

The second part of the regex pattern which checks the length matches every thing even the  and that's why it does not work.

Good luck.

Comment: It is working. I will do my test against more names and let you know.Thank you.

Comment: second expression did not work for string which is more than 40 charecters and contains spl. charecters  SomeSomeSomeSomeSomeSomeSomeSomeSomeSome#

Comment: Surely it won't work alone you have to check for special characters first using the first regex and then once the last name in the xml is all valid and there is no special characters then you go for the second pass and check for length using the second regex.

Comment: Does it solve the problem or it just can't be 2 passes it has to be one pass?

Comment: 2 passes would be fine. I have to run this against bunch of names. And will get back to you soon. Will give upvote and mark as answer .

Comment: This also won't work for `<LastName a='b'>Foo</LastName>` or `<LastName xmlns=''>Foo</LastName>` or `<x:LastName>Foo</x:LastName>`, and it will incorrectly flag `<LastName>O&apos;BrienO&apos;BrienO&apos;BrienO&apos;Brien</LastName>` as being more than 41 characters.

Comment: I got headache of this regex I will not think about it anymore :)